# Linux Mint after upgrade to 5.15.0-75-generic kernel, no sound on headphones

Tags: pulseaudio

I am running Linux Mint on a Lenovo T440p laptop. Configuration:

https://termbin.com/hh3nl

I upgraded to the 5.15.0-75-generic kernel today.
There is no sound on the 3.5 mm socket anymore.
I checked:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep pulseaudio 


Jun 19 16:09:47 jr pulseaudio[1082]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 1
Jun 19 16:09:47 jr pulseaudio[1082]: libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
Jun 19 16:09:47 jr pulseaudio[1082]: libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_10
Jun 19 16:09:47 jr pulseaudio[1082]: libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Jun 19 16:09:54 jr pulseaudio[1501]: libva info: VA-API version 1.14.0
Jun 19 16:09:54 jr pulseaudio[1501]: libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
Jun 19 16:09:54 jr pulseaudio[1501]: libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_14
Jun 19 16:09:54 jr pulseaudio[1501]: libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed
```

I rebooted, and I tried `sudo alsa force-reload` but no change.

Maybe someone has a solution...